# Neumann vs Dirichlet eigenvalue problem - Intuition

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, intuition, spectral-theory

What is the fundamental different between a Neumann eigenvalue problem and Dirichlet eigenvalue problem? I know that for DEP, we just fix the boundary (e.g. a drum), but what about the NEP. Now, consider a rectangle $\Omega = [0,l] \times [0,m]$. Separate variables using cartesian coordinates $x$ and $y$. That is, look for solution of the form $\varphi(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$

*- Dirichlet boundary condition $\varphi| \partial \Omega=0$.*

The eigenfunction are $$\varphi_{j,k}(x,y)= \sin(\frac{j \pi}{l}x) \sin (\frac{k \pi}{m}y) \text{ for } j,k \geq 1$$ and have eigenvalues $$\lambda_{j,k} = (\frac{j \pi}{l})^2 + (\frac{k \pi}{m})^2 \text{ for } j,k \geq 1$$

*- Neumann boundary conditions $\partial_{\nu} \varphi | \partial \Omega = 0 $*

The eigenfunction are $$\varphi_{j,k}(x,y)= \cos(\frac{j \pi}{l}x) \cos (\frac{k \pi}{m}y) \text{ for } j,k \geq 0$$ and have eigenvalues $$\lambda_{j,k} = (\frac{j \pi}{l})^2 + (\frac{k \pi}{m})^2 \text{ for } j,k \geq 0$$

With these informations, does someone could explain to me the difference between NEP and DEP? I would like fundamentally how behave the boundary of NEP.

Comment: Neumann's boundary conditions correspond to a membrane vibrating with non-fixed ends. For the one-dimensional version, see here: http://phet.colorado.edu/sims/html/wave-on-a-string/latest/wave-on-a-string_en.html setting "Loose End" boundary conditions.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Ok, but why mathematical society sets such conditions at the boundary? On the  boundary of a string, how could we interpret the condition $u' \cdot n$?

Comment: It is not the "mathematical society" that sets such conditions. Look at the animation of the string with loose end: you will realize that the derivative of $u$ at the boundary is always $0$, which is the Neumann boundary condition in one dimension.